# Invalid use of non-static member function int test::funcAB(int, int)

Tags: c++

I've got some problem using `std::function`

It works with static int `funcAB` but, in reality, I need std function for non-static in class.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class test{   
    public:
    std::function<int (int, int)> func;
    int funcAB(int a, int b){
        return a + b;
    }
    test(){
        func = test::funcAB;
    }
};

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    test A;
    cout <<A.funcAB(10,11) << endl;
    cout <<A.func(11,12) << endl;
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp:11:22: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘int test::funcAB(int, int)’
         func = test::funcAB;
                      ^~~~~~
```

Comment: pointer to member function is different than pointer to non-member (or static) functions. use std::bind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here:

The first is that to get a pointer to a member function you need to use the address-of operator `&`. As in `&test::funcAB`.

The other problem is that non-static member functions needs an object to be called on. If you don't have an object, you can't call it.

To solve  the second problem either use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

```
using namespace std::placeholders;  // for _1, _2, _3...
func = std::bind(&test::funcAB, this, _1, _2);
```

Or use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

```
func = [this](int a, int b)
{
    return funcAB(a, b);
};
```

Lambdas are generally recommended over `std::bind`.

Comment: You cannot bind `funcAB` to `func` like that. You need to add `placeholders`

Answer (score 1):

Pointer to non-static member functions are different, you have to invoke them with the first argument being an instance of the particular object that the member function shall be associated with. In your case, you can fix this by first correctly declaring and assigning to `func`:

```
std::function<int (test&, int, int)> func;

// ...

func = &test::funcAB;
```

Then, the call side looks a bit different, too. Pass `A` as the first parameter here:

```
cout <<A.func(A,11,12) << endl;
```

Note that there is a different solution. You can leave the `func` declaration as it is and assign a lambda to it that captures `this`:

```
func = [this](int a, int b){ return funcAB(a, b); };
```